# Reverting to Ionic 1/AngularJS searching for stability in 2017

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

We're using Ionic 3 + Angular 4 to replace our native mobile apps, but are worried about stability and bugs encountered so far (virtualscroll, slides/keyboard inputs/etc).

We would like a backup app which is stable enough to put out to production soon. **Is reverting to Ionic 1 a suitable solution? Or is it something that will be obsolete soon and with that its own issues.**

When the bugs are ironed out in Ionic 3+, we'll be looking to submit that to production. I'm fully behind the Ionic project and know that some hacking needs to be done to achieve some things, as well as appreciating the good work they're doing to increase speed and native feel.

Our app is heavy on messages in scrolling lists, so virtualscroll is very much needed soon. Also, two of our 3-person team are very experienced in AngularJS, but not Angular 2+ at all, which is something that would speed up development right now. The existing documentation for Ionic 1 and AngularJS is also attractive right now for us.

Comment: Xamarin from Microsoft is stable enough I think. But it would require you to re-write the UI in XAML

Comment: i'll have a look, but I think the decision is to stay within Ionic

Comment: I think the difference between AngularJS and Angular >= 2.x would be enough to keep me on ionic 2 or higher. Plus, looking on the bright side, ionic 3 does seem better than ionic 2, once you get the app up and running again. It is unfortunate that things like virtually scroll don't work so great. Rather than backing up to legacy versions, perhaps consider contributing to the framework. That's what we do when ionic gets on our nerves. Don't want to get stuck in the past either.